# how can i rotate a function of a square i made in javascript?

Tags: javascript, rotation

How can i rotate this function by 45 degrees so it is a diamond. I am making a game where this function is the player and you can move it with the arrow keys, but i want it to be in the shape of a diamond and not a square.

```
function morty() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,cv.width,cv.height);

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    ctx.fillRect(x1,y1,50,50);

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(175,80,247)";
    ctx.fillRect(x1,y1,45,45);

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(50,100,150)";
    ctx.fillRect(x1,y1,40,40);

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,255,255)";
    ctx.fillRect(x1,y1,32,32);

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(250,0,250)";
    ctx.fillRect(x1,y1,27,27);

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(47,47,47)";
    ctx.fillRect(x1,y1,20,20);

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,0)";
    ctx.fillRect(x1,y1,10,10);

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,200,180)";
    ctx.fillRect(x1,y1,5,5);
}
```

Comment: You may be able to use the rotate function `ctx.rotate(45*Math.PI/180);`

Comment: [ctx.rotate(angle);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate). And remember add it before `ctx.fillRect`s.

Comment: One would rotate what's drawn in the context, not rotate a function

Comment: sorry, im a major beginner. your right, i want to rotate whats drawn in the context.

Comment: @craigo When I do that, my square just keeps flying diagonal over and over again

Answer (score 0):

Your square flying diagonal is because that when you move `(1, 0)` after rotate, you're actually moving about `(0.707, 0.707)` on the canvas, because after the coordinate system is rotated by `ctx.rotate`.

So, what you desire is to make `(1, 0)` translate real have the effect of move `(1, 0)` on the canvas, which should not be rotated, then it's better to move `x1` and `y1` out. The logic becomes,

1. draw some squares on `(0, 0)` (because `ctx.rotate` is center at `(0
   0)`)
2. rotate it
3. Move the square to `(x1, y1)`.

Convert to scripts, we should know that in canvas, the ealier you apply a transform, the later it'll effect. Also, we want to restore the coordinate back after the drawing is complete, so scripts would be:

1. use `ctx.save` to save current, unaltered coordinate, for later we can back to it.
2. We want move `x1, y1` be not affect by rotate, so we first call `ctx.translate(x1, y1);`, that it'll move anything rotated by `(x1, y1)` on canvas.
3. Then call `ctx.rotate(45 / 180 * Math.PI);` to make following drawing operation to rotate by 45 degree.
4. Draw the squares, but this time, instead drawing on `x1, y1`, we draw them centered on `(0, 0)`.
5. Call `ctx.restore`, so if you have other thing to draw, it will still drawn on the normal coordinate instead of the rotated-shifted coordinate.

```js
var cv = document.getElementById('test');
var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
var x1 = cv.width >> 1;
var y1 = cv.height >> 1;

function morty() {
    // Clear canvas
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,cv.width,cv.height);
  
    ctx.save();
    // This make anything below have a x1, y1 translate/
    ctx.translate(x1, y1);
  
    // This rotate any operations below 45 degree at (0, 0) 
    ctx.rotate(45 / 180 * Math.PI);
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    ctx.fillRect(-25,-25,50,50);

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(175,80,247)";
    ctx.fillRect(-22.5,-22.5,45,45);

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(50,100,150)";
    ctx.fillRect(-20,-20,40,40);

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,255,255)";
    ctx.fillRect(-16, -16,32,32);

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(250,0,250)";
    ctx.fillRect(-13.5,-13.5,27,27);

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(47,47,47)";
    ctx.fillRect(-10,-10,20,20);

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,0)";
    ctx.fillRect(-5,-5,10,10);

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,200,180)";
    ctx.fillRect(-2.5, -2.5,5,5);
     
    // This makes the operations after it still have a normal cordinate system.
    ctx.restore();
}


// Test usage.
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode);
  switch(e.keyCode) {
      case 37:
        x1 -= 10;
        break;
      case 38:
        y1 -= 10;
        break;
      case 39:
        x1 += 10;
        break;
      case 40:
        y1 += 10;
        break;
      default:
        return;
  }
  morty();
})

morty();
```

```html
<canvas id="test" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```